# How to use URL from user input in Go?

Tags: go

I am almost absolutely new to Go language and my current problem is to read URL from user input into a variable to be passed as an argument to http.Get().

The following code

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter URL: ")
    txt, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(txt))   // Get object type
    //url := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s",txt)
    url := "http://google.com"
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(url))   // Get object type
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", resp.Status)
    }
}
```

works perfectly:

```
d:\Go\bin>get_status
Enter URL: google.com
string
string
200 OK
```

but when I uncomment line 16 of the code (while commenting out line 17)

```
url := fmt.Sprintf("%s",txt)
//url := "http://google.com"
```

to use URL from user input, I get a problem:

```
d:\Go\bin>get_status
Enter URL: google.com
string
string
Get http://google.com
: dial tcp: GetAddrInfoW: No such host is known.
```

What could be wrong with my code? Please soothe my pain! :)

**Upd**: 
`import "strings"` plus `url := strings.TrimSpace(fmt.Sprintf("http://%s",txt))` fixed the problem.

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input,
>   returning a string containing the data up to and **including** the
>   delimiter.

Comment: @jiang Unfortunately, I can't get it work...

Comment: @Vifonius Even using TrimSpace?

Comment: @jacob No, I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so it appears that `ReadString` includes the delimiter, so you can use `TrimSpace` from the `strings` package. This seemed to do the trick for me.

```
url = strings.TrimSpace(url)
```

Comment: Fascinating! Thank you very much!
The problem was with '\n' at the end of the string!

Comment: Yeha, debugging the object types is much less useful (as Go is statically typed) than printing the actual value with %v (or even %#v).

Comment: @Volker I just wanted to be sure that I got strings in both cases. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Vifonius What else could `func (*bufio.Reader) ReadString(byte) (string, error)` possibly return?

Comment: @Volker Undoubtedly, I should have read the docs more thoroughly. :)
I was just under fresh impression of Elixir where I had to convert URL from string to char list before passing it to :httpc.request function:
url = String.to_char_list(url)